# Number of bits in a stirling number

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computational-complexity, stirling-numbers

I know that the number of bit required for $N!$ is $\Theta(n\log n)$ by the stirling approximation. But what is the number of bits required for a stirling number of the first kind of the form $\left[\begin{smallmatrix} n \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\right]$?

I know that we can upper bound the stirling numbers since, $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left[\begin{smallmatrix} n \\ k \end{smallmatrix}\right] = n!$

Answer (score 0):

It's a good question. I don't know of a nice satisfying answer for the full two-parameter space. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Asymptotics) has good introductory discussion. You'd probably have to dive into papers to see what cases are well known if you're not interested in one of the simple ones they list.